# Skip no returned value of autofilter

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on a code that filters data based on certain criteria and send an email to those with values. I am having troubles in having the code skip sending emails to users that do not have filtered results. Below is the current code I have.

```
nextMonday = Date + 8 - weekday(date,vbMonday)
nextMonday1 = Format(nextMonday, "\W\C m/d")

For roster = 2 to rosterData.rows.count
 empData.AutoFilterMode = False
 empData.Range("4:4").AutoFilter Field:=16, Criteria1:= nextMonday1
 empData.Range("4:4").AutoFilter Field:=25, Criteria1:= ">10000"
 empData.Range("4:4").AutoFilter Field:=28, Criteria1:= rosterData.range("g" & roster).Value

 visible_cells = empData.Range("4:4").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).rows.Count

 if visible_cells > 1 then
     'send email
 else
 end if
Next
```

The first For processes the code as normal but when it hits Next, the visible_cells value sticks to 1 despite having some values still filtered.

empData table:

| Employee | Amount | WC |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Emp A | 10101 | WC 8/2 |
| Emp B | 5000 | WC 8/2 |
| Emp C | 103451 | WC 8/9 |

rosterData table:

| Employee | Email | POC |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Emp A | empa@ | poc1 |
| Emp B | empb@ | poc2 |
| Emp C | empc@ | poc3 |

Code will filter data from empData per employee in rosterData based on below criteria:

- WC should be next week's Monday
- Amount should be greater than 10,000

If criteria is met, apply filter and send email to employee.
If criteria is not met, do not send email to employee (shows no returned data of autofilter)

It's the second criteria I'm having trouble making

Comment: Share with us the structure of your table with some dummy data and show an example of what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best choice is to use tables instead of ranges with filters.
I converted the ranges into tables and I think this solution is quite simple.

[image]

```
Sub SendMaiTo()
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Dim olEmp As ListObject: Set olEmp = ws.ListObjects("tbEmp")
    Dim olRos As ListObject: Set olRos = ws.ListObjects("tbRoster")
    Dim olCol1 As Integer, olCol2 As Integer
    Dim empRng As Range, rosRng As Range, rCell As Range
    Dim arrEmp() As Variant
    Dim nRows As Integer, i As Integer: i = 0
        
    ' define date
    nextMonday = Date + 8 - Weekday(Date, vbMonday)
    nextMonday1 = Format(nextMonday, "\W\C m/d")
    
    ' clear table filters
    If olEmp.AutoFilter.FilterMode Then olEmp.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
    If olRos.AutoFilter.FilterMode Then olRos.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
    
    ' filter table employee
    olCol1 = olEmp.ListColumns("Amount").Index
    olCol2 = olEmp.ListColumns("WC").Index
    olEmp.Range.AutoFilter Field:=olCol1, Criteria1:=">10000"
    olEmp.Range.AutoFilter Field:=olCol2, Criteria1:="WC 8/2"
    
    ' Filter roster data
    Set empRng = olEmp.ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    nRows = empRng.CountLarge
    
    '  Create array
    ReDim Preserve arrEmp(nRows - 1)
    For Each rCell In empRng
        arrEmp(i) = CStr(rCell.Value)
        i = i + 1
    Next
    
    ' Filter rosterdata
    olCol1 = olRos.ListColumns("Employee").Index
    olRos.Range.AutoFilter Field:=olCol1, Criteria1:=arrEmp, Operator:=xlFilterValues
    
    ' range to send email
    Set rosRng = olRos.ListColumns(olCol1).DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    
    ' send mail
    For Each rCell In rosRng
        ' print to immediate window
        Debug.Print "Send mail to: " & rCell.Value
    Next rCell
End Sub
```